# Ruby on Rails Devise I want to redirect to a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am hoping to make a transition to a specific page after successful login.
For example,

`rails g controller Home
rails g model Home`

How can I describe concretely if you override it with the after_sign_in_path_for method?
I would like to make the description of routes.rb as easy as possible. But I do not know what to do.

Comment: Consider this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: @kuri can you describe it little more? above link didnt help??

Comment: Thank you very much. The link was helpful.